# Evenly spacing and center aligning text

Tags: html, css

I have a div (`#itemSelector`) containing a variable type of div (`.item`). I need to evenly space the `.item` divs in the parent div. The `.item` divs have `display: inline-block` and need to stay that way.

Just for clarity: I want the div's contained in `#itemSelector` to get evenly spaced horizontally along the entire width of the div. The amount of divs in the parent can vary.

jsFiddle of the simplest usecase: http://jsfiddle.net/xTZ8z/

**Edit: thirtydot suggested a solution to me which interesting looking**

Created a jsFiddle of it: http://jsfiddle.net/xTZ8z/82/.

Wrapping a div around my `.item` divs with `display: table-cell` seems to work, tho this is not entirely what I'd like. Any other suggestions like this?

Comment: evenly spaced horizontally or vertically?

Comment: horizontally, I updated the question.

Comment: As you might have guessed from the answers, this is almost impossible to do in pure CSS. You could achieve this effect if you use a html table. And that is fine if it really is the best solution. Otherwise you would need some serverside/client side code running to properly align your items.

Comment: Is [something like this](http://jsfiddle.net/xTZ8z/65/) the right idea?

Comment: @thirtydot: not really since this requires the display type to change. I looks interesting tho. This might be on the right track.

Comment: Well, yeah. It's not using `display: inline-block`, and it won't work in IE7 (thanks to `display: table`), so I didn't post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know you stated that you needed to keep your divs with `display: inline-block`, but this method seems to achieve the effect you are looking for.

JSFiddle of the code: http://jsfiddle.net/xTZ8z/40/

---

**EDIT: @Exelian this achieves the desired effect you are looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/xTZ8z/63/**

---

**EDIT: @Exelian This is a slightly altered and commented version of the previous code:
http://jsfiddle.net/xTZ8z/88/**

I hope that helps!

Comment: hmm, ye, but the amount of divs inside the parent can vary, so this isn't an option.

Comment: Well, are you willing to use Javascript? Because you could adjust the width of the item divs based on the number of divs you have with javascript.

Comment: @Exelian Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/xTZ8z/63/ It will adjust the width according to the number of divs on the page. I hope that helps!

Comment: @Exelian I have created an updated version of my code that is commented! I hope that helps! Here is the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xTZ8z/88/ .

Comment: I gotta admit that besides the above mentioned table-cell example auto-magicly setting the value using jQuery might be the best option. Im waiting to see if some others have good suggestions.

Comment: Ok, I hope you are able to find a suitable solution to your problem!

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
#itemSelector {
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px dashed red;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
}

.item {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: grey;
    width: 25%;
    text-align: center;
    height: 100px;
    line-height: 100px;
    margin: -2px;
    padding: 0;
}
```

That should do the trick

[Example here](http://jsfiddle.net/eM76c/)

Comment: hmm, but they don't fill up the entire width of the parent when using this method.

Answer (score 0):

What about a table set to width 100%?

Comment: Well, I was looking to see if it was possible without using a table, but the odds are not looking great :D